# Enable compiz hot corners in second display

Tags: compiz, window-management, multiple-monitors, scale-mode

I have CompizConfig installed on Ubuntu 14.04 with the Unity desktop. I wanted to configure a hot corner so that when my mouse hovered on the top right corner of my screen it would trigger what I normally see when I press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>.

To to this, in Compiz I went to

- Window Management > Scale > Bindings

There, for Initiate Window Picker with the display icon, I selected the `TopRight` corner.

This setting works fine unless I'm connected to a second monitor.

Can this be resolved?

-

**Update 1**

I notice that if I'm connected to a second monitor via the laptop's Mini DisplayPort, the hot corner works. If I'm connected via the HDMI port, it does not.

**Update 2**

This is odd. The hot corner works if my built in display is set to the left, or below the second monitor.

[image: Screenshot of Display setup]

If the built in display is set to the right of the second monitor the hot corner does not work.

[image: Screenshot of Display setup with hot corners not working]

Comment: Thanks for scripting suggestion. I think I'll pass on it for now, perhaps in the future.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, for Unity (Compiz), your screens together make one viewport/desktop. In your second setup, the right side of the left screen is just (a bit further than) half way of your desktop, as seen by Unity.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resolve this issue be making sure the hot corner is accessible by your mouse in the viewport.

*via comment from Jacob Vlijm*,

> for Unity (Compiz), your screens together make one viewport/desktop. In your second setup, the right side of the left screen is just (a bit further than) half way of your desktop, as seen by Unity.